# How do I use target="_blank" or target='_blank' to open links in a new tab?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently edited a theme and need to make the Social Media Icons open in a new Tab. I understand that for this I should use target="_blank" but don't know where to add it into the following code.

```
$output .= "<li class='facebook'><a href='$facebook'>Join our Facebook Group</a></li>";
```

Comment: well, as it is a option/property of your link, it would most likely belong to the `a href` part.

Comment: Please do not downvote the question because it's basic. Downvote questions which show no research effort or are badly formatted.

Comment: @Madara -1 because the op could save everyone some time and goggled this

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Which it is. There is no research effort and it is me who do the formatting.

Comment: 6 downvotes without any comment... it's not the sense of Stackoverflow to downvote beginners questions...

Comment: I really wonder who is voting this up. The initial question showed no research effort at all. I dont know from where the starter got the knownledge of the `target=`, but he could have gone one step beyond and google that. Its those basic questions from people not willing to learn the basics that annoy me - even though I did not downvote, I just gave a hint in my comment and not the copy&pasteable answer

Comment: @Najzero i hear what your saying ... the OP was unsure as per their comment on my answer -> *Thanks! I did try this already but it gives me an error in dreamweaver so was not sure if it was correct?*

Comment: @ManseUK nah, your answer is perfectly fine and did not mean to offend people willing to help by answering that kindly... but I am one of the "whathaveyoutried" askers... and I bewail the soul for useing dreamweaver ( ha, Frontpage 2.0 memories popping up in my head )

Comment: @Najzero i have the same thoughts - but a slightly different attitude - if people are asking this kind of question then i think its my responsibility (as someone with knowledge) to guide that person in the right direction - always linking to the docs where possible ... and we agree on the dreamweaver comment - however some people love it ... (P.S. no offence taken)

Answer (score 6):

Here

```
<a target="_blank" href='$facebook'>
```

**Note**: it will only open in a new tab if the users preferences force it .. ie it might open in a new window

[Docs for `a` HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Thanks! I did try this already but it gives me an error in dreamweaver so was not sure if it was correct?

Comment: @AngeliqueDosSantos it maybe that dreamweavers preview doesnt support this ? (not sure) - it will certainly work in a browser - please make sure you understand the note i added .. you cannot force it to open in a new tab

Comment: @AngeliqueDosSantos The error might come from the fact that this property was deprecated in a previous version of HTML. If you're declared your document as HTML5 it's not a problem. Please see: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a.attrs.target

Comment: @AngeliqueDosSantos Try this in a browser, this will work. `_new` also could be used.

Comment: @2-Stroker and where is `_new` on the HTML spec ? http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.browsing-context-name - while some browsers may be support the `_new` value it certainly shouldn't be used as a cross browser solution

Answer (score 2):

```
$output .= '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/mygroup/">Join our Facebook group</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be an attribute of an anchor tag, as in:

```
<a href='$facebook' target='_blank'>Join our Facebook Group</a>
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks SO SO SO much for alllll your feedback! Where have I been! This forum is awesome!

Comment: Hehe always welcome :P

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='$facebook' target="_blank">Join our Facebook Group</a>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Hey give the `target=_blank` in `<a>` tag

```
<a target="_blank" href='http://www.google.com'></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following forms are correct:

- Single quotation: `<a target='_blank' href='http://some_site.com'>abc</a>`
- Double quotation: `<a target="_blank" href="http://some_site.com">abc</a>`

Comment: However, `some_site.com` is not a great value for the `href` attribute. If the value does not start with a protocol, e.g. `http://` browsers will treat it as a local resource. -1

Comment: My answer has been focused on quote characters not the part 'some_site.com' !!!